# Charting out a Mathematical Learning path for a future career in Computer Science

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, statistics, discrete-mathematics, computer-science

I'm looking for advice on what all things to learn . I am aware of the fact that CS makes heavy use of Discrete Mathematics , Probability , Calculus , Algebra , Statistics .

What all topics from the above , and apart from them , should I study , and in which order ?

I'd also love it if any entry level texts for the same can be pointed out .

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: My recommendation would be to look at the undergrad and grad math CS programs requirements of several of the big name schools around the nation and write out a list. See where they intersect and then repeat it with second tier schools. This will generate a very realistic list.

Comment: My advice to you would be to start with Linear Algebra and/or Probability. With high school math you can get pretty far into the concepts especially linear algebra. Eventually you will hit topics where derivatives and integrals come up. Once this happens you will need to get up to speed with differential and integral  calculus. You could do calculus first but it may be more discouraging.

Comment: Speaking as a mathematician who's working as a programmer, I'd pick a CS problem you find interesting  (theoretical or practical) and work on it until you find some math concept you need and don't know. Learn that, then get back to the problem. Build a web scraper for your favorite sites, or a twitter bot that searches for and replies to very specific phrases. Both will get you knee deep into concurrency and complexity if you want to do them at moderate scale, which will generate plenty of math problems.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are a high school student. If there advisers who are familiar with your background in math so far and who know about CS, then give first priority
to their advice. Second, I like @Moo's suggestion because that method is
empirical and not just based on opinions of people with unknown reputations;
my only modification might be to put some emphasis on requirements at
universities you might feasibly attend.

Now, for my personal opinions, which might be of some use.
I would put primary emphasis on discrete mathematics because it is
directly relevant and perhaps most feasible for self study. 
If you have not already done so, you might try learning a few
computer languages and getting familiar with UNIX (LINUX) operating
systems. Many high school students have done self study of computer languages
that has been helpful later on.

You might consider taking AP statistics if it is taught by someone with actual applied
experience. In my experience, some students are not really ready for
calculus in high school, and get off to a much better start with
college math if they get ready to start lower division calculus 
in their first year, with strong backgrounds in algebra, trigonometry, analytic geometry,
and perhaps the beginnings of linear algebra. Take a formal course in 
linear algebra at the first opportunity,
usually immediately following beginning calculus. If number theory
is a separate course, take it.

Do some reading about various professional opportunities in CS.
Consider which of them appeal to you most and what topics, possibly
including some non-mathematical ones, might be relevant. 
In particular, you might read some introductory books on linguistics, neural nets, or quantum mechanics. If you are a US citizen, you might consider
what kinds of computer careers lead to jobs that are not likely to
get routinely sent to other countries.